# Cheerio.js lodash dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am looking for the most lightweight and fast jQuery implementation for server-side NodeJs. The best option so far I could find is [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/).

I noticed that the code-size for Cheerio is quite large ~2.6 MB. Of this around ~1.4 MB belong to the dependency [Lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Lodash on a quick glance seems to provide small helper functions and my question is how difficult it would be to try to patch Cheerio to work without this dependency, making this dependency more lightweight or if there is already a more lightweight fork of Cheerio available.

Comment: What requirement do you have where performance/file-size is a concern, but also requires you to implement server-size Node.js using jQuery? This sounds fascinating, I am genuinely curious.

Comment: @EdmundReed Thank you for your question. I need this for an online IDE where one can [create components](https://objecthub.io/docs#/Micro_Page) that are defined in HTML, JS and CSS and be rendered on the server (there is also a different component for rendering this on the client). The JavaScript to do this is executed on Amazon Lambda. Now, whenever a user makes a code change in the IDE, an archive with the source code and all dependencies needs to be uploaded to Amazon Lambda. So if this archive is a few MBs smaller that can make a big difference!

Comment: That sounds really interesting, good luck.

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit of a challenge but we are getting there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recommended in [Issue 862](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/862) to update the engine minimum to allow lodash removal, and this was address in [PR 864](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/pull/864) to use loadash as individual modules as per our need instead of having a big bundle.

You can read the [Change Log for Version 4.14.0](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v4140) for more info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it seems that the package.json in the currently deployed cheerio version (and in master branch on GitHub) does not take advantage of selectively loading lodash modules. I have created a [fork on GitHub](https://github.com/mxro/cheerio-lightweight) with a patched package.json. Works like a charm to reduce the download size! Any idea why this is not in the master branch?

Comment: That's what I'm also wondering... Perhaps we should raise a ticket there to find it out.

Comment: Done. I've submitted issue [1085](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1085).